# What's the most efficient way to increase a PositiveIntegerField in a view in Django?

Tags: python, django, database

I have a model with this field in models.py:

```
vote_submissions  = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

In the view, I originally just did a basic

```
object.vote_submissions += 1
object.save()
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

as I am still learning the in's and out's of Django.
From what I understand I should use F() expression?
I have this in my views.py and it works (not tested yet).

```
from django.db.models import F

Category.objects.filter(id=object.id).update(
                vote_submissions=F('vote_submissions') + 1)
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

Is this the most efficient and safest way to do these kind of updates?

Thank you.

Comment: The second will be faster, since you do this with one database query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter will be faster, since you do the increment with *one* query. The former will make two queries: one to fetch the object, and want to update the object. Database queries are "expensive" since usually it requires a lot of work to construct the query, send the query to the database, let the database decode and evaluate the query, send back the results, and evaluate the results. This takes a lot of work.

Important is however *not* to fetch the object first, since otherwise we still make two queries (and therefore the changes will not be that significant). So instead of using `id=object.id`, you should do the filtering with the data you have, like the primary key.

Note that you can use [**`redirect(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) to combine a `reverse(..)` call and the construction of a `HttpResponseRedirect` call, so you can write this as:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def some_view(request, pk):
    Category.objects.filter(id=pk).update(
        vote_submissions=F('vote_submissions')+1
    )
    return redirect('index')
```

Comment: Thank you for the very informative description on database queries. That makes a lot of sense. I get a little lost on filtering with the data I have. Ill do some more looking into primary keys. Ah ok cool thank you! Good to know about redirect. I can change a few of those lol.